# Pronunciation of "xenophobia," "xenon," and "Xena"

Tags: american-english, british-english, pronunciation

I've heard all of the above words with X as *zeh*. Is that an American English thing?
What's the correct way to pronounce each word?

Comment: pronunciation of [xenophobia](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/xenophobia), [xenon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/xenon) and [Xena](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uu4OKynDM5k) are all available online.

Answer (score 4):

When the letter **x** is in the very beginning of the word, the standard way to pronounce it is /z/. This pronunciation is standard English, it isn't restricted to dialects or countries. When its position in a word is other than the very beginning, then the letter **x** is pronounced /ks/ as in ***expect*** or ***fox***.

EDIT upon comment: There are certain for which the /ks/ sound doesn't apply for the letter **x**. ***Exaggerate*** is a good example, as well as the word ***example*** itself, where **x** is pronounced /gz/.

Comment: Actually, that's a little misleading for *expect*.  This would be pronounced /gz/ for many people.  I expect *exaggerate* and *examine* are pronounced with /gz/ for most.  Point is, don't oversimplify how x is pronounced out of initial position.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: The standard pronunciation for "expect" is /ks/. You are right about "exaggerate" and "examine", of course, and I'll edit my answer accordingly. I wanted to make a point of the big difference of pronouncing x when it is in the beginning of a word, the sound /k/ is totally absent.

Answer (score 0):

I grew up in the Midwest, and we pronounced all of them with the "zee" sound.